# Laravel relationship data return

Tags: laravel, relation

I have a table, which has some relationship data which I can get nicely returned, but I need to get a relationship from the returned data as well. This is the `Shop database`, where I'm interested in the `Shop name`. I can only retrieve the `shop_id` from the `shopDepartment` table.

The tables I have is :

```
DailyList
- id
- grocery_id
- amount
- completed

Grocery
- id
- name
- measurement

ShopDepartments
- id
- shop_id
- name
- order

Grocery_ShopDepartment
- id
- grocery_id
- shop_department_id

DailyList_ShopDepartment
- id
- daily_list_id
- shop_department_id

DailyList_priority
- id
- daily_list_id
- priority

Shop
- id
- name
```

This is the relationship from the DailyList Model

```
class DailyList extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function dailylistpriority()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DailyListPriority::class);
    }

    public function grocery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Grocery::class);
    }
    public function shopDepartments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ShopDepartment::class)  ;
    }
}
```

DailylistController

```
public function index() // I need to have relationdata from shopdepartment
    {
        $list = DailyList::with(['grocery', 'shopdepartments', 'dailylistpriority'])->where('completed', 0)->get();
        return $list;
    }
```

This is my output

```
{ "id": 550, "grocery_id": 108, "amount": 1, "completed": 0, "created_at": "2020-03-25 19:45:43", "updated_at": "2020-03-25 19:45:43", "grocery": { "id": 108, "name": "Havregryn", "measurement": "Stk", "created_at": "2020-02-03 09:26:23", "updated_at": "2020-02-03 09:26:23" }, "shopdepartments": [ { "id": 3, "shop_id": 1, "name": "Hygiejne & Pleje", "order": "3", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "pivot": { "daily_list_id": 550, "shop_department_id": 3 } }, { "id": 17, "shop_id": 2, "name": "Ukendt", "order": "0", "created_at": null, "updated_at": null, "pivot": { "daily_list_id": 550, "shop_department_id": 17 } } ], "dailylistpriority": [] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `ShopDepartment.php` class.

```
class ShopDepartment {

    $table = 'ShopDepartments';

    public function Shop()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Shop::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can include nested relations on your DailyList query.

```
$list = DailyList::with(['grocery', 'shopdepartments.shop', 'dailylistpriority'])->where('completed', 0)->get();
```

Comment: I get this error when I do this: ssage: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shopping.shop_shop_department'

Comment: Have you migrated your tables?

Comment: Yes, everything is migrated

Comment: oh you did not use traditional tabgle naming, add this to your shop department class. protected $table = 'ShopDepartments';

Comment: Great. Thank you so much